# Как увеличить количество условий "if" привязанные к одному "else"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Как упростить дерево `if` для их количества более 10, чтобы добавлять разрешенные пути для запуска файлов? Код работает так - файл переносится на приложение, приложение определяет путь файла и его имя, проверяет равно ли значение пути с указанным.

p.s. все значения `if` должны вести только к одному `else` запуска формы

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filePath = args[1];
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string systemFolder = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\\system32\\") + fileName;
    string myFolder = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemDrive%\\my\\") + fileName;
    if (filePath == systemFolder)
    {
        Process Proc = new Process();
        Proc.StartInfo.Verb = "open";
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        Proc.Start();
        Application.Exit();
    }
    if (filePath == myFolder)
    {
        Process Proc = new Process();
        Proc.StartInfo.Verb = "open";
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        Proc.Start();
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать оператор ИЛИ (||)

```
if ((filePath == systemFolder) || (filePath == myFolder))
```

Comment: Слишком длинная строчка получится... Может есть вариант в столбик?

Comment: @Vitokhv тогда используйте переменную типа bool и потом её уже в if

Comment: @Vitokhv var b = filePath == systemFolder; b ||= filePath == myFolder;

Comment: @Vitokhv, можно и в столбик – нажмите в нужном месте Enter и выровняйте пробелами

Answer (score 2):

```
 switch(filePath)
        {
            case myFolder:
            case systemFolder:
                {
                    Process Proc = new Process();
                    Proc.StartInfo.Verb = "open";
                    Proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
                    Proc.Start();
                    Application.Exit();
                }
                break;

            default:
                {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new Form1());
                }
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Подскажите, как приложение поймет с чем сравнивать? Есть `filePath` но нет `systemFolder` и `myFolder`?

Comment: подправил ответ, если нужно добавить еще строки, с которыми хотите сравнить filePath, то добавьте еще метки case.

Comment: Спасибо! Просто я ни разу не видел как работает `switch`. А есть ли вариант, для дополнительного `Proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";` чтобы был запуск с одних папок по `"open"`, 
с других по `"runas"`?

Comment: Что бы запускать для одних папок с одним параметром, а для других - с другим, заведите переменную string verb и инициализируйте её в зависимости от вашей папки, а Proc.StartInfo.Verb присвойте verb. Но лучше начните с изучения языка, почитайте, например, Герберта Шилдта.

Comment: Для `case` требуется постоянное значение, уже и `string systemFolder = @"C:\"` подставлял, ничего...

Comment: В общем для `case` указание переменной не работает, только статика `case @"C:\Windows\system32\sysfile.exe":`

Comment: Учите язык, читайте, что пишет компилятор. case работает с переменными, но эти переменные должны быть инициализированы.